# SQL LEFT JOIN WHERE not displaying right result

Tags: sql, join, group-by, where-clause

So I got this query:

Data structure:
Users
id---inlog----name----more stuff

llntoets
id---code----inlog----more stuff

oefeningen
id---speler---status----morestuff

(inlog and speler are always the same values for a user)

```
SELECT
// Some other stuff working
SUM(o.status) AS oefn
FROM    users AS u
LEFT JOIN     llntoets AS l
ON (u.inlog = l.inlog)
LEFT JOIN     oefeningen AS o   
ON (u.inlog = o.speler) AND o.status = 'afgewerkt'
WHERE
code = '$code'
GROUP BY l.inlog
ORDER BY klas ASC, klasnr ASC
```

Everything runs fine except 1 thing the oefn variable. It shows a number sometimes it shows the correct value and sometimes it shows a value that is much higher than it should be. Someone told me it could be because of the GROUP BY. Can someone help me pls?

It is supposed to count the total records from table oefeningen where status = 'afgewerkt' and where the speler is the inlog from users. Thanks, if you got other questions ask will try to explain more.

Comment: You probably have a 1:M relationship you're not expecting. Inclide l.inlog in your select, order by it, and remove the group by statement. Now find one of the l.inlog values that had a much higher SUM than you expected and see why you have those rows included in your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `SUM(o.status)` in your query it is not supposed to count the total records of table `oefeningen`.
that sum is the sum of the values of all the joined rows that satisfy your criteria that can be a much higher number.
also note that applying the filter `o.status = 'afgewerkt'` you are performing a `JOIN` even if you wrote `LEFT JOIN` throghout the query.

Comment: Hey, tried to change it and edit SUM to COUNT, and made a JOIN of it. But now I have a new problem, sometimes it counts only the rows with status is 'afgewerkt' and sometimes he gets all rows. Any idea?